# Outputting a map in a specific order

Tags: c++, sorting, maps, output

Hopefully I can explain  exactly what's going on, but basically I have a map of words and their corresponding line numbers on a document that is read in by the program. I can output the map and everything with the words and their line numbers but I'm confused on how to change how they output. So here is the code:

here is the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include "dictionary.h"
#include "document.h"

using namespace std;

void sentancetoword(string sentance, set<string> words, int lineNum)
{
    dictionary d;
    document doc;
    bool wordCheck;
    string word;
    stringstream ss(sentance);

    while (ss >> word)
    {
        wordCheck = d.findWord(word, words);
        if(!wordCheck)
        {
            doc.missingMap(word, lineNum);
        }
    }
    doc.displayMap();

}

string letterCheck(string sentance)
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sentance.length(); i++)
        {
            if (!isalpha(sentance[i]))
            {
                sentance[i] = ' ';
            }
        }
    return sentance;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    dictionary dic;
    document doc;
    set<string> words;
    set<string>::iterator it;
    string doc_word;
    int lineNum = 1;
    ifstream in;
    in.open(argv[1]);
    string word;

    while (in >> word)
    {
        transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
        words.insert(word);
    }

    in.close();

    //dic.makeSet(words);

    ifstream in2;
    in2.open(argv[2]);
    while (getline(in2, doc_word))
    {
        transform(doc_word.begin(), doc_word.end(), doc_word.begin(), ::tolower);
        doc_word = letterCheck(doc_word);
        sentancetoword(doc_word, words, lineNum);
        lineNum++;

    }

    in2.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}


#include "document.h"


document::document(void){}
document::~document(void){}

void document::missingMap(string word, int lineNum)
{
    misspelled[word].push_back(lineNum);        
}
void document::displayMap()
{
    for (map<string, vector<int>>::iterator i = misspelled.begin(); i != misspelled.end(); i++)
    {
        cout << i->first << ": ";
        for (vector<int>::iterator j = i->second.begin(); j != i->second.end(); j++)
        {
            cout << *j << endl;
        }
    }



}
```

so the last function is doing the outputting of the map and it outputs as follows:

```
debugging: 1
process: 2
removing: 2
programming: 3
process: 4
putting: 4
```

but i need it to output like this:

```
debugging: 1
process: 2 4
programming: 3
putting: 4
removing: 2
```

is there something I'm doing wrong in the code or do i need to add a sort function to sort it by the words? I'm honestly lost and don't know where to go from here to get it to output only the word one time followed by the line numbers it appears on. If anyone could help that would be great, and if any more information is needed I'll be happy to add it to the question! Thanks!

Comment: Why is `misspelled` defined in the constructor instead of the class body?

Comment: I don't have any idea what you did to get that output, but [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb51c8680ade73a9) is about the best I can do to recreate an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Please fix it into something that exhibits your problem.

Comment: @user3009714 My question was not meant to make you remove that part from the question. You should post the code you actually tested verbatim, whether it is correct or not. (Also see the comment above)

Comment: @user3009714 So, you see the improvement points for your question, I've mentioned to you earlier. But you're tending getting better: Hooray! No downvotes so far, and an answer that sounds sound ;) .. Keep on!

Comment: I doubt that is the output… maps are sorted by key, which in this case is a `std::string`, these are sorted lexicographically, which means that `removing` cannot appear before `programming`… that is unless you have some characters that you are not showing (additional spaces?)

Comment: Thats why i am so confused by the output. Ill look and see if i can find anything but when i compile the code thats what i get as the output

Comment: i put in my main function, i haven't seen anything out of the ordinary that would be making my map output like that, there is a function that  will get rid of the punctuation with a space, i don't know if that would affect anything. Hopefully it helps

Answer (score 1):

Your output doesn't make sense, though I think you will want to do this:

```
cout << i->first << ": ";
for (vector<int>::iterator j = i->second.begin(); j != i->second.end(); j++)
{
    cout << *j << " ";
}
cout << "\n"; //endl is okay, but I prefer only for I really do need to flush the stream
```